# Change default currency to preferred currency in Receipt Card Bot Framework

Tags: asp.net, botframework, bots

I am trying to implement a receipt card using bot framework C# but it keeps displaying currency in USD. I have tried to change the currency from where the API endpoint is hosted from $ to what I want but still currency does not change. Any idea what am not doing right?

```
CardAction pbv = new CardAction()
{
    Value = "Check Status",
    Type = "imBack" 
};

ReceiptCard plCard = new ReceiptCard()
{
    Title = "Little Live Fare",
    Items = new List<ReceiptItem>
    {
      new ReceiptItem("TRIP STATUS",subtitle:status, image: new CardImage(url: img_url)),
    },
    Total = "500.00",
    Tax = "0.00",
    Tap = pbv
};
```

I want the **Total** to display as **KES: 200.00** instead of **$ 200.00**. 
Still on the same, can one customize the card and omit Tax from displaying on the receipt?

Comment: Your code is not valid and we don't even know what is your `res` object where you populate the values you are talking about, so it's impossible to help

Comment: Code updated @NicolasR

Comment: "I mean what else could be parsed on Total and Tax if not amount"... Maybe something including a currency for example? That's not with that kind of comment that you will get help, sorry.

Comment: Withdrawn and updated @NicolasR

Comment: Which channel are you trying to send the ReceiptCard over?

Comment: Hello @StevenG , at the moment facebook but with intentions of doing skype telegram and slack too

Comment: Do you try to explicitly add it `Total = "KES: 500.00"` and comment out the code snippet for Tax `Tax = "0.00"`? Besides, if specific channels still render Tax field even though you comment out the code, you can report the issue on [github issues](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues).

Answer (score 1):

In the receipt card there is a property of `Facts` which is `List<Fact>` in these facts you can set the currency type.  It appears the currency types follow the [ISO 4217 Standard](https://www.xe.com/iso4217.php)  Which you can also find the [corresponding symbols](https://www.xe.com/symbols.php).

```
Facts = new List<Fact>
{
    new Fact("currency", "KES")
}
```

I will show you the code I am using below, but this is how it renders on slack and facebook respectively:

Facebook:

[image: FaceBook Receipt Card]

Slack:

[image: Slack Receipt Card]

I also  was able to exclude tax from showing by just not including a tax parameter as you can see in the code below:

```
        Activity reply = activity.CreateReply();
        reply.Attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        var receiptCard = new ReceiptCard
        {
            Title = "John Doe",
            Facts = new List<Fact>
            {
                new Fact("Order Number", "1234"),
                new Fact("Payment Method", "VISA 5555-****"),
                new Fact("currency", "KES")
            },
            Items = new List<ReceiptItem>
            {
                new ReceiptItem("Data Transfer", price: "KSh 38.45", quantity: "368", image: new CardImage(url: "https://github.com/amido/azure-vector-icons/raw/master/renders/traffic-manager.png")),
                new ReceiptItem("App Service", price: "KSh 45.00", quantity: "720", image: new CardImage(url: "https://github.com/amido/azure-vector-icons/raw/master/renders/cloud-service.png")),
            },
            Total = "90.95",
            Buttons = new List<CardAction>
            {
                new CardAction(
                    ActionTypes.OpenUrl,
                    "More information",
                    "https://account.windowsazure.com/content/6.10.1.38-.8225.160809-1618/aux-pre/images/offer-icon-freetrial.png",
                    "https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/")
            }
        };
        reply.Attachments.Add(receiptCard.ToAttachment());
        await context.PostAsync(reply);
```

Comment: Thank  you so much. This really helped. Currency issue is fixed. On the other issue about tax, facebook still displays tax when you click the receipt card. All the same this solution works for me....

Comment: I noticed that too.  That seems to be completely on the Facebook side as I do not see a way to change that.  I'll look into this a little more today, but it seems as it is out of our control from the bot code perspective.  I didn't see anything in the facebook receipt template API call to alter this.

Comment: Yeah, it seems its on Facebook side. I've already configured slack and telegram and the receipt is just fine.... On facebook too its ok apart from when the receipt is clicked to see more details where the tax now displays.